# MySQL in visual studio express for windows phone

Tags: mysql, windows-phone

Is there any way I could use MySQL database in Windows phone App development?? And what are the databases can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

For a mobile development an embedded database like [SQL Server compact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/) or SQLite would be more appropriate. Maintain a database server inside a mobile device is not a good idea, even if it's possible.